# Keyboard is going out while moving one text field to another text field

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have two textfields as emailTextField and passwordTextField.

I have written the following textfield delegate methods for moving one text field to another:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

    if (textField == emailTextField) {

        [textField resignFirstResponder];
        [passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if (textField == passwordTextField) {

        [textField resignFirstResponder];

    }

    return YES;
}
```

When I click to next button after entering email then it will go to password textfield but within a fraction of a second, the keyboard will disappear.

What is the solution for this? Is there a mistake in the code?

Comment: did you write anything in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` method ?

Comment: no. I did not written anything in textFieldDidBeginEditing.

Comment: you can use iqKeyboard manager for this case.

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{

   if (textField == emailTextField) { 

      [passwordTextField becomeFirstResponder];

  } else if (textField == passwordTextField) {

       [textField resignFirstResponder];

  }

  return YES;
}
```

Comment: still keyboard is going while after comming to passwordTextField.It moves to passwordTextField but withins secs keyboard will disappears.

Comment: see if you have a target textFieldShouldReturn to password textfeild in project

Comment: in project, anywhere you write `[passwordTextField resignFirstResponder];` or `[self.view endEditing:YES]` ??

Comment: I used urlTextField like  [self.urlTextfield becomeFirstResponder]; It is in same view controller

Comment: one at a time should be becomeFirstResponder

Comment: what I done is that, In view controller I taken 2 views. One is urlView - here I will check url of website and in second view I will check email and password